# Moment.js "Invalid date"

Tags: jquery, datepicker, momentjs

I just tried to make a text input with formatted date. It is working fine on Google Chrome, but when I run it on Mozilla Firefox (26.0) it says: `Invalid date`.

You can see and run [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/MMm86) in both browsers and hopefully understand the problem.

JS Code:

```
$( "#h_reg_date" ).datepicker();
$("#h_reg_date").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-M-dd");

$("#save_data").on("click", function(){
 var reg_date = $("#h_reg_date").val();
  console.log(reg_date);
  reg_date =  moment(reg_date).format("YYYY/MM/DD");
  console.log(reg_date);
  return;
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="h_reg_date"class="abs" style="top:135px; left:150px;" size="10" readonly >
<input type="button" id="save_data" class="abs" style="top:370px; left:-200px;" value="Add Data">
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the format of the `datepicker` to:

```
$("#h_reg_date").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy/mm/dd");
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/MMm86/1/

To put the date in your requested format use:

```
$( "#h_reg_date" ).datepicker();
$("#h_reg_date").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy/M/dd");

$("#save_data").on("click", function(){
 var reg_date = $("#h_reg_date").val();
  console.log(reg_date);
  reg_date =  moment(reg_date).format("YYYY/MMM/DD");
  console.log(reg_date);
  return;
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/MMm86/2/

Comment: I already know that.. but I need to display date format in 2013/Jan/31.
Is there any other js or solution to make this fine?

Comment: Yeahh... I got it.. but I want to display date as 2013-Jan-31. but it should get to var as 2013/01/31

Comment: @SameeraSilva Your comments are confusing me, in the first comment you wanted `2013/Jan/31` in the last one you ask for `2013-Jan-31`?

Comment: ohh.. Im sorry... When I change separator from '-' to '/', it works.. But why it is not working on 2013-Jan-31?

Answer (score 52):

Suppose your date is in format 'DD-MM-YYYY' & you want to display it in DD-MMM format then you can do this by first telling moment function which format your date currently is & then asking it to convert it to required format. Below is the example:

```
var taskDueDate = moment(dueDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MMM');
```

This way you can convert your date in any format.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be a known issue, per their docs.
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Looks like they suggest passing in the time string and the format.

Comment: Is there any other solution to make this fulfill?

Comment: Thank you sir. The part with passing the known format to the method worked for me